# Как запустить Windows 11 через grub

Tags: grub, windows-11

Мне нужно запустить Windows 11 через Grub. Я установил Ubuntu в качестве 2-ой системы через USB bootable, перешёл на Windows 11. После этого я удалил том диска с Ubuntu, чтобы опять установить другую систему. Но при перезагрузке появился терминал grub.